# First power of 2 below a number

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, pic

The following code snippet is a student attempt to write a lookup-table in PIC assembly. The
code is supposed to return the first power of 2 below a number N. So for the value 10 tha answer
should be 8, for 7 it should be 4.

```
nop
nop
retlw 8
Nop
Nop
Nop
retlw 4
Nop
retlw 2
Nop
retlw 0
lesspow subwf PCL, F
```

how could I Rewrite the code above using a subroutine that uses any instructions except add and
subtract.

Comment: What if the input was already a power of 2?  For input = 8, is the result 8 or 4?  If it's 8, then you're basically isolating the *highest* set bit.  If PIC can count leading zeros, that could help.  Otherwise you could loop clearing the lowest set bit (`x &= x-1`) until it becomes zero, then return the previous `x`.  Assuming you can implement `x-1` without a `sub` instruction one way or another.

Comment: if it is power of two it return itself .... could you please help me with the code .... thanks alot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your homework:

```
lesspow:
    movwf   temp
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    clrc
    rrf     temp,F
    iorwf   temp,W
    movwf   temp
    rrf     temp,F
    xorwf   temp,W
    return
```

No**w** you can add the appropriate comments.

Comment: thank you....     but why can not I add appropriate comments?I did not get it ....and I have a question what is "irowf" instruction ? ..... thank you again

Comment: @Dan: an uncommented code dump and no explanation of an algorithm is basically never a good answer for Stack Overflow; it doesn't help future readers very well.  This is also basically the opposite of the answering guidelines in [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if you care about those.  If you think it's an interesting question worth answering, just answer it properly, IMO.

Comment: @PeterCordes, The Original Posters question is the same class of example code. In my opinion this answer is only just as good as that. If you believe that this answer should be deleted say so an I will do it straight away.

Comment: @Dan1138: I think if I had to choose between uncommented working code vs. deleting it, I think I'd say we should keep it.  If I knew the PIC ISA, I could presumably figure out what it was doing.  (But it's not one of the ISAs I'm familiar with, and its mnemonics are more cryptic than some; I think I see a clear carry flag and rotate right as part of it...).  But ideally adding 1 or 2 sentences to describe the algorithm would be the best thing for this answer.

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate all your efforts.. thank you very very much